# Windows docker command line cannot accept inner commands

Tags: windows, docker, command-line, docker-for-windows

I have windows docker installed and when I run this on command line:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
```

I get:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'q' in -q)
```

But when running:

```
docker ps -q
```

Everything is alright. Any clues?

Comment: Try to practice docker latest command execution format. Check it using docker --help

Comment: Have you installed docker toolbox?

Comment: No, I have installed Windows for Docker. And updated to the newest version this week: Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40.

Comment: Try this docker container stop $(docker container ls)

Comment: result:

    Error response from daemon: No such container: $(docker
    Error response from daemon: No such container: container
    Error response from daemon: No such container: ls)

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with passing the inner command, but I cannot find out what...

Comment: Is this docker container ls command give you any container list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(sub command)` is a syntax of the bash shell (along with many other command shells on Linux). If you try to run this from a Windows command prompt, it will not be correctly expanded before running the rest of the command and you'll see the errors you're encountering. Try installing and running the commands on bash for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I used this in Windows:

```
powershell docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a little trick to stop all containers :

```
docker ps -a -q | xargs -n 1 -P 8 -I {} docker stop {}
```

It does not contain $ symbol, so should be correct

Answer (score 0):

You can also [enable Bash shell](https://itsfoss.com/install-bash-on-windows/) within Powershell on recent releases of Windows 10 and the use the $ command